# How to change value of a dropdown list from a SQL select?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I need to update the displayed value of a drop down list from the results of a query.

This is an asp.net webform in c# using a sql db and all data needs to be handled in the codebehind.

This page is intended to update the Building table.
The building table contains a companyID that corresponds a company code in the company table.

On page load I call GetCompanyCodes() and fill the drop down with the available company codes from company. Then I call BindForm() which fills in the the two other text boxes and a check box on the form using a stored procedure that joins the company table and returns the appropriate company code for the companyID listed in the building table.

What I can not figure how to do is to change the displayed value of the drop down list when I load in the data from the Building table.

I have no issue setting the value of the other controls, just the drop down.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: There are tons of examples online on how to do that...

Comment: Well then you must be better at choosing the right keywords, because my research has led me to asking for help because I haven't been able to turn up a resource that is helpful.
Care to share an example you know of?

Comment: show the code of your BindForm

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is the data returned by the `SqlDataSource` which is set as the data source of the `DropDownList`:

[image]

Now, for displaying the company name in the `DropDownList` you should go to the DropDownList Tasks and then Choose Data Source. Then in the Data Source Configuration Wizard windows, select the `CompanyName` as a display field and the `CompanyId` as a value field. Later, if you wanted to update the `DropDownList` just call the [DataBind()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd7t67ef(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
this.DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is like this, by specifying the text and value fields from the source.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource = loadFromDataBase();
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This helped with part of the issue, I posted an answer that contained the second issue.  Now I've created a new one, care to assist with this as well?

Comment: In the sql query you use `@CompanyID`, while in the parameter it is `@Company_ID`.

Comment: Wow, I've been staring at this for so long I didn't even notice.  That took care of the "must declare" error, but there is still no value in the drop down when I call my update method.

Comment: Move the databinding of the dropdownlist inside the `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: My page load has an if (!IsPostBack) that calls the methods, first company then bind form.

Comment: Usually when a DropDownLists is empty or at it's default value after a PostBack, the data is being (re)bound to the Control causing it to loose it's selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to get the value I wanted to the drop down, but now I can't access the value of the drop down for a different call.

@VDWWD, you corrected part of the issue - I was calling .SelectedValue and .DataTextField was what did the trick.

The other part of the issue is that I was trying to get to the .SelectedItem to the columne name when I bound the form, but what it needed to be was .SelectedItem.Text